# A listener to a fragment without calling the fragment in android

Tags: java, android

Im calling a fragment(ImageFraggment) from an actvity(MainActivity) , and created a interface on that fragment. And also i have implement Listner in Main activity. you can  see the code below.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ImageFragment.imageEventListener  {

   //Calling ImageFragment

    @Override
    public void eventListner(int number) {
        log.d("MainActivity",number);

    }
}
```

ImageFragment.java

```
public class ImageFragment extends Fragment {
    private imageEventListener imageEventListener;


  //enter a number
  //if number equal to 1
  {
    imageEventListener.eventListner(number);
  }


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            imageEventListener = (imageEventListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement imageEventListener");
        }


    }


    public interface imageEventListener {
        void eventListner(int number);
    }
}
```

This code works fine, means when user enters 1,log will display it(from mainActivity).

But now im trying to Listen to same event from another activity(AnotherActivity)(which doesnot call ImageFragment) as shown in below code.

AnotherActivity.java

```
public class AnotherActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ImageFragment.imageEventListener  {
   //I dont call imageFragment here    
     @Override
     public void eventListner(int number) {
         log.d("AnotherActivity",number);

     }
 }
```

But im unable to print the number using log, How can i resolve this?I'm missng any major thing here?

Comment: use event bus library.

Comment: What i'm doing wrong here?

Comment: why you want to listen event in other activity is this Fragment has any service or async task which completed after opening Another Activity?

Comment: I use ImageFragment to display images, i want to send name of currently displaying image to AnotherActvity(actually its just a class). which will later sent to the server.

Answer (score 0):

At first, it will help you if you know the observer pattern: https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/observer

According to the observer pattern:

ImageFragment is a subject.
MainActivity and AnotherActivity are observers.

If you want to listen to an event from the subject, you need to register the observers first.

Look at your ImageFragment:

```
 @Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        imageEventListener = (imageEventListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement imageEventListener");
    }


}
```

In here, you have registered only MainActivity(you said that: "which doesn't call ImageFragment"), for this reason, you will not able to listen to that event from that activity if you don't call/start that Imagefragment from that activity.

Thank you.

Comment: MainActivity does calls the fragment, and able to listen to the even. AnotherActivity(which is actually just a class) unable to listen to the event.

Comment: How can i register AnotherActivity here, the above code which you have pointed doesnot have any reference to MainActivity but it still registers MainActivity.!

Comment: You are registering via, imageEventListener = (imageEventListener) activity on -> onAttach() method.

And, if you understand the answer, you may tick the answer. It may help others.